# Countif with arrayformula many condition in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a task. Could someone help me please.
I need to count in each row how many tasks are over deadline with arrayformula.

Here is an example:   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eGo5M1P1OmPU09jND7clc2fn7Z3Awe2JEpf2IhNvuE0/edit?usp=sharing
Sheet "deadline" Instead of using `=COUNTIF(....))`, how can I solve such task with arrayforumla. Totally there will be 15 task and deadlines.

Comment: If there will be 15 tasks and deadlines, I suggest you set up your sample spreadsheet to reflect a layout that has 15 tasks and deadlines. Otherwise, even if someone helps with a formula, you may have a hard time adapting it to your real spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, to avoid confusion and frustration for others, I recommend that you move your data currently in cells D4 and E4 (i.e., "in work" "Task 8") over to cells E4 and F4, since that is where it seems they belong.